# Binding Multiple VertexArrays - OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, vao

Can you bind separate VAO's `glBindVertexArray(m_vaoID);` with geometry defined in two separate functions `createGeo();` and `createGeoAgain();` and then use the `glDrawArrays(...)` function twice to draw the individual Objects in one display function?

Currently, I define two squares' vertex's in one array (`12 vertex's`), in one function... but say I wanted separate arrays to hold each shapes vertex's? (`6 in each`)?

I tried it, and it only ever rendered one... So I'm confused on the binding...

Comment: I am confused by your question. If all you want to do is draw from different vertex ***BUFFERS***, you can create two VAOs each of which has its own set of bound VBO(s) and vertex pointers and you can switch the bound VAO out between calls to `glDrawArrays (...)`. Alternatively, you can use a single VAO and modify the bound VBOs and vertex pointers between draw calls (this is the old way of doing things). VAOs are really just a mechanism to allow you to change multiple vertex array properties in a single API call (by storing a collection of states in a container object).

Comment: Sorry. It's because I don't really understand what VAO and VBOs are. I can not find a good explanation anyway for someone with little experience... I assumed each object you wanted to draw had to have its vertices stored in a VAO and each VAO is Bound by a VBO... leading to needing multiple of each...